# Laravel Sanctum Gives Error When Creating Token

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to setup `Sanctum` for logging in to my `Laravel` api. I am following the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum) (also cross-referenced other articles online) but I'm getting an error back when I try to get a token with `createToken`:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime
> format: 1366 Incorrect integer value:
> 'd0970066-b343-419a-a348-9d43df3c13b4' for column
> `mydb`.`personal_access_tokens`.`tokenable_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert
> into `personal_access_tokens` (`name`, `token`, `abilities`,
> `tokenable_id`, `tokenable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
> (mydevice,
> 2fde2030c7dcede42cbf76124b77fe0edbbff75fe01ae57ef25a3f582123ee93,
> ["*"], d0970066-b343-419a-a348-9d43df3c13b4,
> App\Models\User, 2021-07-12 13:19:17, 2021-07-12 13:19:17)) in file
> D:\dev\...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php
> on line 692

It appears the `tokenable_id` column is expecting a different value than what Sanctum is giving it. The database wants a `bigint` but is getting a `string`. Why is this happening?

---

here is the migration file:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->morphs('tokenable');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
            $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

The table:

[image]

Error happens when this line is called.

```
return $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
```

Full code [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#issuing-mobile-api-tokens).

Comment: are you are using UUIDs for `users`?

Comment: Yes, I am using UUIDs for users.

Comment: well then the migration would have to be adjusted to not use a bigint for that column since you have a string column for ids not integers (for `users`) ... `morphs` creates a column with big int to match what the `id` method creates

Comment: I see! I didn't realize that was the user id being passed. Makes sense!

Comment: that is why they added `uuidMorphs` to do the same thing except it creates a string column for the id instead of an integer column

Answer (score 2):

To solve that error change

```
        $table->morphs('tokenable');
```

to this

```
        $table->uuidMorphs('tokenable');
```

Hope this helps, I was struggling with the same problem and after changing mine worked

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your table migrated, you need to change the specific *tokenable_id* column and not the morphs columns as morphs & uuidMorphs both return null, so `->change()` cannot run. Instead use:

```php
$table->uuid('tokenable_id')->change();
```

If you have not run the migrations yet, then you can just change the main migration file using @lagbox's & @Mwangi_Muthui's suggestion of:

```php
$table->uuidMorphs('tokenable');
```

Please let there is a better way to change morph tables.